# Form should only submitted into database if difference field value is 0

Tags: php, forms, conditional-statements

I have small debit credit form. I am trying to do that form should only submitted if value in 3rd field difference is 0. Otherwise it should generate error that value is not 0.

here is my form

```
         <html>
         <body>
          <form method="POST" action="test.php">
             <label>Debit:</label> <input type="text" name= "debit1"  id= "debit1" class="form-control" Required>
<label>Credit:</label> <input type="text" name= "credit1"  id= "credit1" class="form-control" Required>
<label>Difference:</label> <input type="text" name= "diff1"  id= "diff1" class="form-control" Required>\
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-success >
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is backend file in php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $debit1 = $_POST['debit1'];
        $credit1 = $_POST['credit1'];
        $diff1 = $_POST['diff1'];

}
require_once "config.php";
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO iap3 (debit1, credit1, diff1) 
             VALUES ('$debit1', '$credit1', '$diff1')";     
           $rs = mysqli_query($con, $sqlInsert);    

  
    // close connection
    mysqli_close($con);    ?>
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. When you post code in a question, please review it, that it is properly formatted. That also gives you the opportunity to review the code you ask about a little more, which often helps to find such bugs. E.g. right now the insert query is always run as you have placed it out of the if-body. Properly indenting code helps you to spot such errors more easily.

Comment: Preventing the form from being submitted if a particular value is zero or whatever should be done using Javascript. To prevent the PHP from being executed if a value is zero (or whatever) is different - which is it that you are trying to do? Prevent the form submission or prevent the PHP from being run?

Comment: You are using the `label` tags incorrectly. A `label` should be associated with an input element either using `for=ID of input` type syntax or by nesting the input element within. The above does neither so the label elements are not associated with anything

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. **Never** use user supplied input data directly in the SQL - you should **always** use `prepared statements`

Comment: How is the difference calculated? Is that the difference between credit and debit? Relying upon values supplied by the client is risky as they are easily modified

Comment: @Professor I want to prevent form from submission if difference is not 0. and this difference will be calculated by me vfrom debit - credit. But i want how can i do that if value in diff field is 0

Comment: As mentioned - to actually prevent the form from being submitted at all must be done using Javascript but should not be trusted completely, especially if there is money at risk. The Javascript to prevent form submission is fairly simple

Comment: can u send example if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of preventing the form submission if the value of `diff1` is not zero. As stated previously - do not implicitly trust this difference value if it is important within the PHP code!

The prevention is accomplished using `event.preventDefault()` where the `event` is registered using a delegated listener looking for the `submit` event.

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLFormElement && parseFloat(e.target.diff1.value) !== 0) {
    alert('Bogus - the Difference is NOT zero!');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
label{display:block;width:30%;padding:0.25rem}
label > input{float:right;width:25%}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
  <label>Debit: <input type="text" name="debit1" class="form-control" required value=1 /></label>
  <label>Credit: <input type="text" name="credit1" class="form-control" required value=2 /></label>
  <label>Difference: <input type="text" name="diff1" class="form-control" required value=1 /></label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```